# Do/did famous actors that are part of Game of Thrones actually go nude?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have recently started watching *Game of Thrones* and I noticed that it has many well known actors like Peter Dinklage, Emilia Clarke, Sean Bean, Natalie Dormer and so on.

By famous I mean, actors that are seen in many other movies.

Did these actors really go nude, that is, the bodies we see in the series are their real bodies or have body doubles been used?

I read an article where they explained how they used body double for Lena Headey in the nude penance walk scene of Cersei Lannister. So for other actors (like Emilia Clarke or Natalie Dormer) who are seen naked, was it a real body or just another body double?

Comment: “I noticed that it has many well known actors like Peter Dinklage, Emilia Clarke, Sean Bean, Natalie Dormer and so on” — well-spotted!

Comment: I read that Leanna Headey body in S05E10 was photoshopped with a double so she could focus on play

Comment: @Vinz243 Actually Leanna as pregnant during the time they shot the "walk of shame" so they used a body double. Small side note there. In the book Cersei gets shaved from head to toe ;)

Comment: I've never been creeped out by a question before...

Comment: @Thomas It's Lena, not "Leanna". Considering the walk was [filmed in October](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/61955/20150619/how-lena-headeys-walk-of-shame-nude-scene-was-filmed-for-the-game-of-thrones-finale.htm) and she gave birth [in early July](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/lena-hedley-baby-girl_55a032dde4b0a47ac15c965a), she can't have been along very far. Lena herself has never mentioned her pregnancy as  a reason, neither have the makers of the series, so please don't present this as a fact.

Comment: @BCdotWEB no idea, why I wrote her name wrong. But regarding sources: http://www.inquisitr.com/2175159/lena-headey-defends-cerseis-walk-of-shame-in-the-game-of-thrones-finale/ or http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3125348/Lena-Headey-used-body-double-brutal-nude-walk-shame-Game-Thrones-season-finale.html
Though it seems I misread it as the reason for the double...

Comment: **how much percent or how many body parts we see on nude body are real and body double based?** that sentence alone gives me the creeps!!

Comment: @BCdotWEB Lena and baby hippo are doing great!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **[Emilia Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emilia_Clarke#Filmography)** and **[Natalie Dormer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalie_Dormer#Filmography)** were big stars before the *Game of Thrones* TV series started (check the wiki links). Their career kind of took off after *Game of Thrones*. While Sean Bean and Peter Dinklage were around for a long time and critically acclaimed.

Coming back to all the nudity in *Game of Thrones* series, most of the actors have actually gone nude for their scenes.

There are couple of interviews by the lead ladies which points towards the same.

**[Natalie Dormer on nudity](http://www.inquisitr.com/1628378/the-game-of-thrones-scene-that-natalie-dormer-refused-to-do/)**

**[Emilia Clarke on Game of Thrones](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/event/article-3021427/Game-Thrones-Emilia-Clarke-women-remove-items-clothing-Game-Thrones.html)**

**[Emilia Clarke won't allow any more khaleesi naked scenes](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/daenerys-nudity-emilia-clarke-wont-allow-any-more-khaleesi-naked-scenes-game-thrones-season-4-video)**

**[Emilia Clarke reveals a game of thrones sex scene secret](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/06/emilia-clarke-reveals-a-game-of-thrones-sex-scene-secret)**

Comment: Natalie Dormer was fairly famous because of _The Tudor_.